# How to perform a SQL Server update in a specific order?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server update statement in a stored procedure that violates a constraint during its execution, but the constraint is valid once the entire update statement has completed.

The statement is:

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET FieldA = 1 WHERE FieldB = @SomeFieldBValue;
```

Rows in the table SomeTable form a hierarchical relationship with child rows referencing parent rows. The constraint ensures that parent rows cannot have FieldA set to a non null value, unless all child rows have FieldA set to a non null value.

So, for example, let's assume that SomeTable contains the following data:

```
Id | ParentId | FieldA | FieldB
-- | -------- | ------ | ------
1  | NULL     | NULL   | 123
2  | 1        | NULL   | 123
```

Now when the update statement executes it fails with a constraint violation because row 1 is not allowed to have FieldA set to a non null value unless all its children have FieldA set to a non null value.

Temporarily disabling the constraint is not an option as the user does not have the permission to do this.

Comment: And update statement does not process in some sort of order. It is a set based operation. You would need to perform 2 separate update statements here.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to remove ordering assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a trigger like this accomplish the same thing?

```
create trigger ...
if exists (
    select i.Id
    from
        inserted i left outer join inserted i2
            on i2.ParentId = i.Id
    group by i.Id
    having not (count(i.FieldA) = 0 or count(i2.FieldA) = count(i2.Id))
) rollback;
```

Comment: I used a version of this thanks. It actually led to a more readable constraint because I was able to reference a computed column. I understand there are perils in using triggers but in this case to implement the constraint as a trigger made the most sense and gave a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Never use WHILE loops in SQL, SQL is a Set based language and not procedural.  Just select the parent and all children into a #TEMP table, update the temp table rows, delete the originals and insert the new ones:

```
BEGIN TRAN

  SELECT Id, ParentID, FieldA, FieldB, 
  INTO #TEMP1
  FROM SomeTable
  WHERE FieldB = SomeValue

  UPDATE #TEMP1 SET FieldA = 1

  DELETE SomeTable where FieldB = SomeValue

  INSERT SomeTable Set ..... FROM #TEMP1
COMMIT
```

Comment: Replace Last DELETE with INSERT SomeTable FROM #TEMP1

Comment: Messes with auto generated primary keys?

Answer (score -1):

If you can't disable the constraint, I'm afraid you can't do that with a single statement. You'll have to create a loop and manually perform the updates in the "correct order".

Pseudo-code:

```
Begin Transaction
Do
    recordsAffected = UPDATE SomeTable 
                         SET FieldA = 1 
                       WHERE (FieldA IS NULL OR FieldA <> 1)
                         AND FieldB = @SomeFieldBValue
                         AND NOT EXISTS (child with FieldA set to null);
While recordsAffected > 0
Commit Transaction
```

Translating this to T-SQL or the client language of your choice is left as an exercise. :-)